# How can I create a dynamic link in a macro using excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I'm relatively new to the excel macro writing and so I was wondering if you guys could help me. I want to create a dynamic link to a cell in another closed workbook. I need the information in the master workbook to change as the user changes the values in certain cells. For example, lets say the value in cell A1 is 11 and the value in cell A2 is 22. I need A3 to link to cell C6 in the file 11-22.xls. If I were to change the value in A1 to be 33 and the value in A2 to be 44 then I need A3 to link to cell C6 in the file 33-44.xls. Please include detailed code to complete this task since I am so new to writing macros. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a macro that opens the 'master' spreadsheet, changes it, saves is and closes it again.

To get started, check out these MSDN entries:

- [Workbooks.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3k79a5x.aspx)
- [Workbooks.Active](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh14x010.aspx)
- [Workbooks.Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd8yh918.aspx)

Warning: If you want more than one user or file accessing the master at a time you'll run into problems.